Designing a 12AU7 Tube Preamp with Stable 120V Plate Supply – Seeking Suggestions
I'm designing a small preamp using the 12AU7 tube. For my plate voltage, I'm using a rectified output of 132V DC from a transformer, which I want to regulate down to a stable 120V. The goal is to ensure the voltage remains unaffected by load variations. I've designed a small circuit to maintain the voltage at a steady 120V. However, I'd appreciate any recommendations or suggestions for improving the design, identifying potential issues, or confirming if this approach will work effectively.
Thanks.


I can’t see how your circuit regulates. Maybe look at using a LM317. Hopefully the TI datasheet still has the old National Semiconductor applications where a high voltage regulator circuit was shown.

Old tube supplies, those I built and those I copied from decades ago, were mostly a series resistor (high wattage) paralleled to a series inductor (heavy and big) and capacitors with bleeder resistors across the capacitors (which may be stacked in series and parallel, or not.) That doesn't mean I'm claiming it's good (or bad.) It's just what was done. How well regulated does this need to be (what does unaffected mean) and why?

For a preamp, your main capacitor is too large: typically about 2000uF is used for each ampere of current, 4700uF at the most (except for some special cases). Seems that the current will be about 100+mA, so I wouldn't use more than 220-470uF. Better place for filtering the AC ripple would be at the base of the regulating transistor: there you can use much larger value of the base resistor R1 (like 10k), and a larger C2 (like 22uF to 100uF, see what gives good enough results). Remove R3 and R4, place a 120V zener diode in parallel with C2, increase R2 to 1k to limit maximum base current.

I also don't see the need for C1. C3 can be made as small as 10uF, but it shouldn't do harm if left as 100uF: it mostly reduces load transients.

mmmm i'm gonna try with the zener.

Hi @Periblepsis,
Could you recommend any books or resources on designing power supplies, specifically for building triode preamps? I’ve been having trouble finding information on this topic and would greatly appreciate any guidance you can offer.
Thanks!

@Zlmanuel87 What I learned on were either old handed-down books from military training manuals circa 1940's and 1950's or else ARRL handbooks. Later, of course, once the internet was established, there are very good locations to go -- including many good youtube content providers. The problem I'd have in making a recommendation would be my lack of knowledge about your background, experience and knowledge, and what you are wanting to achieve.

In keeping with historical tube design, I'd use a glow-tube regulator, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage-regulator_tube,  e.g., OB3 or two NE-2 neon lamps. Though you might not get exactly 120 VDC, short-term regulation is more important in a preamp.
